# What does 'enemy fire' mean here?

Tags: phrase-meaning, phrase-usage

The [Wiktionary](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/nicety) gives the following as an example sentence for the use of 'nicety':

> "We met the new captain while we were taking enemy fire and were
> unable to observe the niceties of formal introductions."

In the sentence, what does the expression 'taking enemy fire' mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 'new captain' has presumably been posted to an army unit while it is engaged in combat.

Comment: You mean **to take enemy fire** means **to engage in a combat**?

Comment: It means that they were being shot at by the enemy!

Comment: ok, in a passive sense. Thank you.